# Eigenvectors of block diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, direct-sum, sparse-matrices

Consider a finite dimensional block diagonal matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
A = \bigoplus_i A_i,
$$
where $A_i$ are mostly the **0** matrix (of some finite dimension), i.e. the matrix is very sparse.

**Is there a nice property of block diagonal matrices that lets me independently diagonalise the $A_i$'s and then somehow glue the result to diagonalise the full $A$?**

(I am numerically solving for the eigenvectors of a large sparse matrix and I am running out of memory and sparse coding representations don't help)

Comment: Yes, you can just diagonalize each block separately. You just need to identify the eigenvectors of $A_i$ with the eigenvectors of $\bigoplus_i A_i$ which lie in the subspace spanned by the basis vectors whose corresponding rows and columns are covered by $A_i$ in the block diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  But since the dimension of the eigenvectors of $A_i$ is smaller than that of $A$, how would one go about "padding with zeros" the eigenvectors of $A_i$ so that it matches the dimension of $A$? Say $A=\mathbb{0}_{2\times 2}\oplus M \oplus \mathbb{0}_{3\times 3}$, where $M$ is some 2x2 matrix, how would it look like?

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is an eigenvector of $M$, you can pad it like $(0,0,x,y,0,0,0)$ to make it an eigenvector of $A$. There's a more abstract way to do this by embedding the space on which $M$ acts into the space $A$ acts on with an injective linear map. There's a natural way to do this for direct sums of vector spaces, which yields that the image of $(x,y)$ under this embedding is $(0,0,x,y,0,0,0)$.

Comment: Right, so the eigenvectors of $A$ have the general form $v_i = (0, \cdots, 0, a_i^{1},\cdots,a_i^{N_i},0,\cdots, 0)$? Where $N_i$ is the dimension of $A_i$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.